# How to decide which layer to use in a CNN for feature extraction?

Tags: feature-selection, conv-neural-network

Bear with me since I'm new to this stuff and a thousand google searches (and a dozen or so papers) wasn't able to answer my question.

I'm working on my thesis which involves classification of blood cells using Convolution Neural Networks. However, I'm not going the transfer learning route and instead only using the CNN to extract features.

I understand that initial layers in a network output the low level features (lines, edges etc) whereas later layers move towards high level features (shapes, patterns etc.).

My question: How do we decide which **layer** to get output from as our features? Generally, fully connected or pooling layers are used but suppose I want MORE than 1x1x100 features, is it OK to simply take features from a previous layer?

Sharing an image of the last few layers of a network.

Layer **pool10** returns 100 features. Suppose I need more than 1000. Can I simply choose **relu_conv10** instead? Will this cause any issues or poor(er) results?

[image: Layers]

P.S. This network is trained on CIFAR-100 hence the 1x1x100 in the softmax layer.